# Silhouette Cameo Stencil Machine on Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, software-installation, software-recommendation

Can the Silhouette Cameo Stencil Machine work with Ubuntu and if so what do I need to do to get it going? Or are there alternatives that would work the same?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because hardware compatibility questions are off-topic at this site.

Comment: This is a software compatibilty question as far as drivers and software to actually run this machine.

Answer (score 1):

Tux Plot v4 Pro can be used for the Silhouette Cameo Stencil Machine and is available from its [Homepage](http://securetech-ns.ca/tuxplot.html)

[Tux Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2jCz.png)